# Asymptotic analysis of a product of logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

*It may have been already done, but I have found the answer nowhere...*

---

**Context.**

We already know by Stirling's formula that

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n.$$

We can deduce from this that

$$\log(n!)\sim n\log n.$$

**The question.**

But what about $$P_n:=\prod_{k=2}^n \log k.$$

Is possible to conduct an asymptotical analysis for $P_n$, and to find a simpler expression of its growth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural approach is to consider
$$\log P_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\log\log k$$
and apply the [Euler-Maclaurin summation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Answer (score 4):

The natural approach is to consider
$$ \log P_n = \sum_{k=2}^{n}\log\log k $$
then notice that $\log\log k$ is approximately constant on short intervals.
By applying [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we get:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \log P_n &=& (n-1)\log\log n-\int_{2}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor-1}{x\log x}\,dx\\&=& O(1)+n\log\log n-\int_{2}^{n}\frac{dx}{\log x}+\int_{2}^{n}\frac{\{x\}}{x\log x}\,dx\\&=&n\log\log n-\frac{n}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log^2 n}\right). \end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the [Abel–Plana formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2), it can be shown that
\begin{align*}
\prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\log k}  =\; & C\cdot (\log n)^{n + 1/2} \exp \!\left( { - \int_2^n {\frac{{\text{d}t}}{{\log t}}} } \right) \\ & \times\!\left( 1 + \frac{1}{{12n\log n}} + \frac{1}{{288n^2 \log ^2 n}} +  \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 \log n}}} \right) \right)
\end{align*}
with $C = 1.6352358009117223 \ldots$, or explicitly
$$
\log C =  - \frac{3}{2}\log \log 2 - 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\text{e}^{2\pi t}  - 1}}\arctan \left( {\frac{{2\arctan (t/2)}}{{\log (t^2  + 4)}}} \right)\text{d}t} .
$$